# How to get access token in facebook ios

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I am developing an app in iOS for Facebook login. I can log in with Facebook, but I could not get the access token.

This is my delegate method:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject:AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    print("at delegate")
    var configureError: NSError?
    GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
    assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    FBSDKLoginButton.classForCoder()

        return  FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,

                                                                      didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions)
}
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    print("at delegatehg")
            return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation) || GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                                                                                                                                                                                 annotation: annotation)
}
```

And with my viewcontroller, I have a button in the storyboard for the Facebook login. 
This my content inside button:

```
@IBAction func fbLogin(sender:  FBSDKLoginButton) {       

      if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil){
            print("token is not nil")
            let Level2 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("facebook") as? UIViewController
            self.presentViewController(Level2!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else{
        var fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        fbLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"], handler: { (result, error) -> Void in

            if (error == nil){
                var fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
                if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
                {
                    self.getFBUserData()
                    fbLoginManager.logOut()

                }
            }
        })
    }
    }
    func getFBUserData(){
        FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"name,email,picture.type(large),gender"]).startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

            let strName: String = (result.objectForKey("name") as? String)!
                        print(result)
            let Gender : String = (result.objectForKey("gender") as? String)!
            let Id = (result.objectForKey("id") as? String)!
            let deviceId = UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor?.UUIDString
            let UUID = NSUUID().UUIDString
            print(UUID)
            var DeviceId = deviceId
            print(DeviceId)
            print(Id)
            print(Gender)
            print(strName)
            var strEmail : String
            if ((result.objectForKey("email") as? String) != nil){
                strEmail = (result.objectForKey("email") as? String)!
            }else {
                strEmail = "not available"
            }
            //let strEmail: String = (result.objectForKey("email") as? String)!

            var userID = result["id"] as! NSString
            var facebookProfileUrl = "http://graph.facebook.com/\(userID)/picture?type=large"
            print(strEmail)

            print(strEmail)
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://projects.svirtzone.com/wified/api/authentication.php")!)
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
            let postString = "username=\(strName)&email=\(strEmail)&action=auth&pic=\(facebookProfileUrl)&dob=1989/05/05&logintype=Facebook&gender=\(Gender)&device_type=Mac&facebookid=\(Id)&agerange=15&deviceid=\(deviceId)&accesstoken=fdfsfs"
            request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
                guard error == nil && data != nil else {                                                          // check for fundamental networking error
                    print("error=\(error)")
                    return
                }
                if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                    print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                    print("response = \(response)")
                }

                let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print("responseString = \(responseString)")
            }
            task.resume()
            let Level2 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("facebook") as? UIViewController
            self.presentViewController(Level2!, animated: true, completion: nil)

            if (error == nil){
                print(result)
            } 
         }
```

One thing I noticed is that when I am logging in to Facebook, it doesn't call `application() method` in appDelegate. It also did not add a line inside my code `loginView.delegate = self`. This may be reason for my problem, and I don't know how to add that line according to my code.

When I try to get access token by this line:

```
 var token = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString
 print(token)
```

I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegate method:

```
- (void)fbDialogLogin:
(NSString *)
token expirationDate:(NSDate *)
expirationDate
```

Comment: for more information you can refer to the following question :Facebook Access Token

Comment: can you say me clearly please @ Bandna Prasher

Comment: Like...fbdialoglogin

Comment: (NSString *) Gives the string info......token expiration date is when the token exires.....What else?

Comment: where have to add this line ? I am working in swift